# jquery catch previous class issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html is

```
<input type="text" class='myclass' value="start">
<div>
    <input type="text" class='myclass' value="sea">
</div>
<button class="mybutton">Catch</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" value="end" class='myclass'>
```

and javascript is

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev('.myclass').val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

I want to get the value of immediate previous input value by class name. but the result is `undefined`.I want to get the value `sea`. Where is the problem? the working fiddle link is [Here >>](https://jsfiddle.net/Iftakharul_alam/3fnuj382/) Thank you.

Comment: *"immediate previous input"*. That's the problem, it's not immediate.

Comment: In the other word the closest previous input. I tried by .closest() but same result

Comment: closest traverses DOM tree vertically up, while you want horizontal traverasal. Prev checks immediate sibling, and prevAll check all previous.

Answer (score 3):

Immediate previous element of `catch` button is a `div`, so you need to do a `find()` inside that
like this:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev('div').find('.myclass').val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the value of immediate previous input

Well, that's the problem, input is not immediate. you can use [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method instead:

```js
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prevAll('.myclass').val();
    alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='myclass' value="start">
<div>
    <input type="text" class='myclass' value="sea">
</div>
<button class="mybutton">Catch</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" value="end" class='myclass'>
```

Comment: I want to get the value `sea`

Comment: Oh, in this case take a look at Beginner's answer, this is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I have never used the ".prev()" function before. Anyways:

If you read here https://api.jquery.com/prev/ you will find:
*"Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .prev() method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements."*

Also:
*If no previous sibling exists, or if the previous sibling element does not match a supplied selector, an empty jQuery object is returned.*

So in other words, as has been mentioned before, the ".prev()" simply looks for the previous element.

To do what you want to do in the way you want to do it you might want to consider the ".prevAll()" function that is explained here: https://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

But then again since the element you want is actually a child of the previous element and not a direct sibling you might want to consider Beginners' suggestion:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev('div').find('.myclass').val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

But in fact you should be able to make it slightly simpler by removing the 'div' selector:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).prev().find('.myclass').val();
    console.log(text);
});
```

As long as you are certain that your '.myclass' element will be a child of the previous element this should work irregardless of what the parent element is (div, span, whatever)